# How to use `cut` or `sed` to delete few characters or a word only from the beginning of output and not from every line of output?

Tags: bash, shell

Generically speaking, Given a possible some command output like this:

```
one two three four five
six seven eight
one nine five two
etc...
```

I want to use `sed` or `cut` (or possibly other command that doesn't require additional installation on macOS) to remove just the first `one` at the beginning of the stream.  Just the first word on the first line.  All the rest of the output should be unaffected (i.e. `one` on the third line should remain in the output).  How can I do that?  (All SO posts I've seen do it for every line, which is not what I want.)

(EDIT:) I.e. desired output is:

```
two three four five
six seven eight
one nine five two
etc...
```

Additional context:  I need to run a remote command via `ssh` that requires `sudo`.  My script collects the password from users and then echos it into `ssh`'s stdin, and the command ssh runs is `sudo -S`.  `-S` causes `sudo` to read password from stdin, but it still echos "Password:" to stderr.  In order not to confuse user with second pointless prompt, I want to zap it out from stderr output, but I do want the rest of the stderr output in case command that `sudo` runs does generate stderr output.

EDIT (& ANSWER):
So I asked a classical [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) question. I thought the solution was to filter out "Password:" from the beginning of output, but found a more elegant solution to the actual problem of not confusing the user since code wasn't actually asking for the password.

The solution really was to use sudo's `--prompt` to simply change the prompt and thus convert it from input prompt to just an informational message like so:

```bash
cat <<- EOT | ssh "$target" "sudo -S --prompt='Updating files on remote.' rsync ...
$password
EOT
```

This way, no need to run additional process and create longer pipeline, and is simpler.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus, added the desired output, and by now, desired solution, which was different from one asked (XY Problem).

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/one \(.*\)/\1/;:a;n;ba' input_file
two three four five
six seven eight
one nine five two
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `sed` script that only applies to the first line. For example,

```
$ sed '1s/one //' tmp.txt
two three four five
six seven eight
one nine five two
etc...
```

The address `1` means that the `s` command is not applied to any line except line 1.

Answer (score 1):

**CODE**

```
{m,g}awk 'NF<=NR || NF=NF' FS='^[ \t]*one[ \t]+' OFS=  # if u prefer FS/OFS

     or

{m,g}awk 'sub("^[ \t]*one[ \t]+",NR==!_?"":"&")_'      # if u prefer sub()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
two three four five
six seven eight
one nine five two
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and removing **any** first word (separated by any number of spaces):

```
awk 'NR==1 {sub($1 " *", "")} {print}'
```

###edit
Use `sub` instead

Comment: yours doesn't actually do what you think it does : yours scub out EVERY copy of the 1st word, regardless of whether a trailing sequence of blanks exists or not ::::::::::::
echo 'one nine five two one seven eight onethree' |  awk 'NR==1 {gsub($1 " *", "")} {print}'
nine five two seven eight three

Comment: My bad. Changed.